# Javascript design pattern for rendering a component in function of its data type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I have implemented a chat bubble that can render `Images`, `GIFs`, audios, and `text`.

Currently, what I am doing is the following:

```
const Bubble = memo(
  (props) => {
      const { colors } = useTheme();

      const { content, date, mine, onLongPress } = props;

      const renderText = () => (/* JSX FOR TEXT */);

      const renderGIF = () => (/* JSX FOR GIF */);

      const renderAudio = () => (/* JSX FOR AUDIO */);

      const renderImage = () => (/* JSX FOT IMAGE */);

      return (
           <...>
               {content.type === VALID_CHAT_MESSAGES_TYPES[0]
                    ? renderText()
                    : content.type === VALID_CHAT_MESSAGES_TYPES[1]
                    ? renderAudio()
                    : content.type === VALID_CHAT_MESSAGES_TYPES[2]
                    ? renderImage()
                    : renderGIF()}  
           </...>
      )
});
```

I want to refactor this component but I am not sure about which pattern should I apply... Any ideas?

Comment: VALID_CHAT_MESSAGES_TYPES do the array holds the function names?

Comment: ["text", "audio", "image", "gif"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution, using `dictionary` with `callback function` value  like below

```js
const renderText = () => console.log("JSX FOR TEXT");
const renderGIF = () => console.log("JSX FOR GIF");
const renderAudio = () => console.log("JSX FOR AUDIO");
const renderImage = () => console.log("JSX FOR IMAGE");
var renderDict = {
  "text": renderText,
  "audio": renderAudio,
  "image": renderImage,
};
function renderByType(type){
     renderDict[type]();
     //              ^ remember to call function here
} 
renderByType('text');
renderByType('audio');
```

The second solution, using `switch..case`

```js
const renderText = () => console.log("JSX FOR TEXT");
const renderGIF = () => console.log("JSX FOR GIF");
const renderAudio = () => console.log("JSX FOR AUDIO");
const renderImage = () => console.log("JSX FOR IMAGE");

function renderByType(type){
            switch(type){
                case "text": renderText(); break;
                case "audio": renderAudio(); break;
                case "image": renderImage(); break;
                
                default: renderGIF();
              }
} 
renderByType("text");
renderByType('audio');
```

Comment: you are missing return statements from your switch cases, and `renderByType` function.

Comment: No, bro. it depends on the implementation of the `render` method. For example, I just `console.log` so no need to return anything.

Comment: your `console.log` disguises the error in your code. OP needs to be a valid JSX to be returned. your solution only return `undefined`

Comment: what about spliting the component in 4 having a "wrapper" which returns one component or other based on the type?

Comment: I mean, will this be a better approach to manage component state without overlaps?

Comment: how about change to `const renderText = () => myText` and do `console.log(renderByType('text'))` and check what you get

Comment: I was just trying to give you a HU to fix your code to fit the OP needs exactly, and your answer could be accepted by OP. But if you find it offensive and prefers to give a half answer right that's your choise.

Comment: No offensive, mate. I mean the problem here is how to call the function by `type`. And I also believe that the OP knows the way to return it ^^!

Answer (score 0):

You can map the functions via object

```
const Bubble = memo(
  (props) => {
    const {
      colors
    } = useTheme();

    const {
      content,
      date,
      mine,
      onLongPress
    } = props;

    const renderText = () => ( /* JSX FOR TEXT */ );

    const renderGIF = () => ( /* JSX FOR GIF */ );

    const renderAudio = () => ( /* JSX FOR AUDIO */ );

    const renderImage = () => ( /* JSX FOT IMAGE */ );

    return ( 
    <... >
     {({
          text: renderText,
          audio: renderAudio,
          image: renderImage,
          gif: renderGIF
      }[content.type])()} // map and initialize the function 
     </...>
    )
  });
```

It's an object which has key and their function names, we are accessing the key using `content.type` and then execute the object value( i.e the functions themselves)

Comment: What does this answer make the difference with [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65911922/12582716) ?

Comment: If I remember your answer was quite different the first time I saw, It's still better than writing the switch case explicitly, I'll leave it here.

Comment: Yeah, happy coding ^^!